# Generated code from XSD does not accept valid XML in WCF REST endpoint

Tags: .net, wcf, xml-serialization

I have an XSD and I want to define a WCF REST endpoint to recieve an element from the XSD.

I'll explain what I am doing

Consider the following Schema

```
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="dir">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:element ref="dir" />
                    <xs:element name="file">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" />
                            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Here is some valid XML for that schema

```
<dir name="root">
  <dir name="foo">
    <file id="12" name="ha" />
    <file id="12" name="ha" />
  </dir>
  <dir name="bar" />
  <file id="12" name="ha" />
  <file id="12" name="ha" />
</dir
```

If I use XSD.exe to generate the classes from the schema I am able to create the XML above doing the following:

```
dir foo = new dir{dir1 = new dir[2], name = "root", file = new dirFile[2]};
foo.file[0] = new dirFile{id = "12", name = "ha"};
foo.file[1] = new dirFile { id = "12", name = "ha" };
var file = new dirFile[2];
file[0] = new dirFile { id = "12", name = "ha" };
file[1] = new dirFile { id = "12", name = "ha" };
foo.dir1[0] = new dir { name = "foo", file = file};
foo.dir1[1] = new dir {name = "bar"};

XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(dir));
ser.Serialize(Console.Out, foo)
```

Now lets say I want to use that as an input in a WCF REST XML endpoint

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "doit"]
public void doit(dir data) { /* process it */ }
```

If I look at the help page for that service it shows an XSD and valid XML that are drastically different than what I defined manually in the XSD.  If I try posting the xml i generated earlier to that service I get the following error

```
The exception message is 'Unable to deserialize XML body with root name 'dir' and root namespace ''
```

How do I define a web service that receives the XML I defined in the XSD?

EDIT:  Here is the XSD and XML generated on the REST help page.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Thomson.Quiz.Web.Services.Models" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Thomson.Quiz.Web.Services.Models" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="dir">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="dir1Field" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfdir" />
      <xs:element name="fileField" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfdirFile" />
      <xs:element name="nameField" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="dir" nillable="true" type="tns:dir" />
  <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfdir">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="dir" nillable="true" type="tns:dir" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="ArrayOfdir" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfdir" />
  <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfdirFile">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="dirFile" nillable="true" type="tns:dirFile" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="ArrayOfdirFile" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfdirFile" />
  <xs:complexType name="dirFile">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="idField" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="nameField" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="dirFile" nillable="true" type="tns:dirFile" />
</xs:schema>
```

And here is the example xml

```
<dir xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Thomson.Quiz.Web.Services.Models">
  <dir1Field>
    <dir>
      <dir1Field>
        <dir>
          <dir1Field i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
          <fileField>
            <dirFile>
              <idField>String content</idField>
              <nameField>String content</nameField>
            </dirFile>
            <dirFile>
              <idField>String content</idField>
              <nameField>String content</nameField>
            </dirFile>
          </fileField>
          <nameField>String content</nameField>
        </dir>
        <dir>
          <dir1Field i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
          <fileField>
            <dirFile>
              <idField>String content</idField>
              <nameField>String content</nameField>
            </dirFile>
            <dirFile>
              <idField>String content</idField>
              <nameField>String content</nameField>
            </dirFile>
          </fileField>
          <nameField>String content</nameField>
        </dir>
      </dir1Field>
      <fileField>
        <dirFile>
          <idField>String content</idField>
          <nameField>String content</nameField>
        </dirFile>
        <dirFile>
          <idField>String content</idField>
          <nameField>String content</nameField>
        </dirFile>
      </fileField>
      <nameField>String content</nameField>
    </dir>
    <dir>
      <dir1Field>
        <dir>
          <dir1Field i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
          <fileField>
            <dirFile>
              <idField>String content</idField>
              <nameField>String content</nameField>
            </dirFile>
            <dirFile>
              <idField>String content</idField>
              <nameField>String content</nameField>
            </dirFile>
          </fileField>
          <nameField>String content</nameField>
        </dir>
        <dir>
          <dir1Field i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
          <fileField>
            <dirFile>
              <idField>String content</idField>
              <nameField>String content</nameField>
            </dirFile>
            <dirFile>
              <idField>String content</idField>
              <nameField>String content</nameField>
            </dirFile>
          </fileField>
          <nameField>String content</nameField>
        </dir>
      </dir1Field>
      <fileField>
        <dirFile>
          <idField>String content</idField>
          <nameField>String content</nameField>
        </dirFile>
        <dirFile>
          <idField>String content</idField>
          <nameField>String content</nameField>
        </dirFile>
      </fileField>
      <nameField>String content</nameField>
    </dir>
  </dir1Field>
  <fileField>
    <dirFile>
      <idField>String content</idField>
      <nameField>String content</nameField>
    </dirFile>
    <dirFile>
      <idField>String content</idField>
      <nameField>String content</nameField>
    </dirFile>
  </fileField>
  <nameField>String content</nameField>
</dir
```

Comment: Please show the resulting, incorrect XML.

Comment: Updated with incorrectly generated xml/xsd from the rest help page

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing your design pattern you are using. You might want to consider improving your naming conventions for improved readability. I would also remove the redundant use of:

```
<dir1Field>
    <dir>
      <dir1Field>
        <dir>
```

which you have in your xml document.  Try a simpler:

```
<Directory>
  <Files>
    <File>
     <name />
     <id />
    </File>
 </Files>
 </Directory>
```

Try to use a strongly typed object and decorate the object with the appropriate attributes as outlined below. Following the instantiation of the local object in your script, 
You can use the var keyword as you have done above, and populate the fields as you would any normal object property. In your case you will have to consider creating a backing object to hold all the necessary file information you require (name,id etc.)

```
 /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(ElementName="Directory")]
    public partial class 
    {

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("File", IsNullable = false)]
        [XmlArray(ElementName="Files")]
        public File[] FileFieldCollection{ get; set; }

    }
```

Populate your FileField object as required and you should be fine.

Comment: The first schema/xml is what I want.  I know workarounds that don't get that XML or that don't use the default Serializer.  That's not the issue.  I want my original schema.  The second schema and xml are what is used by WCF when i use XSD.exe on the original schema.  As you noted they produce redundant XML and it's not as pleasing.  I want a solution that uses my original schema while also using standard POCO with attributes for marshalling/unmarshalling.